# How to create a certain tree bark geometry and wrap it around a hollow cylinder

Tags: mesh, sculpting, 3d-printing

I would like to model a tree bark for 3d printing as attached.
I am aware of these tree bark textures that one can import and use with a displacement modifier but I find it doesn't work well for 3d printing or at least as a Newbie I cannot manage it.
So would it make more sense to manually create the "protrusions" as shown my red marker using Bezel curves and somehow wrap it around the existing cylinder mesh?

Or perhaps there is an effective sculpting brush I could use?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: yes sculpting is probably the best thing to do

Comment: @moonboots:ok, Il try the blob brush.

Comment: why not the default brush (Draw)?